# XMPPClient with vysper server gets no response

Tags: ios, xmppframework, apache-vysper

everyone I'm trying to implement a xmppclient on iOS.I start from the example in XMPPFRAMEWORK.But I can't connect to my server,which is apache-vysper-server.After receiving a xml,client send a xml to server. But there is no response ever. what is wrong?Is the tls setting mismatch or?

SEND: ?xml version='1.0'?>

SEND: stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='vtc365.com'>

RECV: (stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"  from="vtc365.com" version="1.0" id="0c726f4d2a694b69897069a818447ee3"/>

RECV:(stream:featuresxmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams(starttls>xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">(required/>(/starttls>(/stream:features>

SEND: starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>

RECV: proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
 allowSelfSignedCertificates

SEND: stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='vtc365.com'>

Comment: looks like establishing the encrypted communication gets stuck. can you enable more logging on the client or server?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're connecting but then you don't authenticate. Are you invoking `-authenticate:error` in your delegate's `-xmppStreamDidConnect:` method?